# Indexing and searching words and word-parts

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I just indexed a bunch of text data from our products DB. My goal is evaluating Apache Solr for production use.

This is a document example:

```
{
   "shape":"Geometric",
   "color":"MATTE BLACK",
   "gender":"unisex",
   "model":"CLUBMASTER RX 5154",
   "sales":10,
   "lens":"rugged",
   "material":"plastic",
   "brand":"Ray-Ban"
}
```

The most important thing in our search app is fuzzy matching, because inaccurate search terms are very frequent.

So, I'm a little disappointed with results found by Solr.

For example:

```
clubmaster -> many results
club master -> no results
```

Why?!

```
ray ban -> many results
rayban -> no results
```

I also tried putting ~1 or even ~2 after my term, with no luck!

All fields are indexed '*_txt_en' predefined field.

Comment: [ShingleFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-ShingleFilter) might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just run a serious production setup without customizing schema/solrconfig to fit your specific needs. From what I can guess, you would get the results you want by:

1. copy your text fields into different versions with different analysis, for example:

   - one as a string type, hard to match
   - one field that is using [EdgeNgram](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-EdgeN-GramFilter) to match prefixes.
   - another with WordDelimiterFilterFactory to match ray-ban/rayban
   - ...
2. using [edismax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser) as the query parser
3. in edismax, there are many things to tweak in it. But the most important is: search on all the fields above, but weight then in different way, the less analysis, the more weight

Comment: "one field that is using EdgeNgram to match parts of word on start".... can you please give me something to read about it, for my specific case (clubmaster - club master)?

Comment: added a link to the doc. But the best to understand how it works is to set an example field, and see it work in the Analysis page of Solr dashboard